# Can not understand the right shift operators operation in c for negative numbers

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have this simple piece of code. 
can anyone explain why the output is `ffff` not `0fff` ??

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

   printf("\n%x",(-1>>4));

   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to avoid shifting negative numbers. For `<<` it is undefined behavior. For `>>` it is implementation defined:

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type
>   or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>   part of the quotient of `E1 / 2`<sup>`E2`</sup>. **If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined**.

Comment: can i have a little more elaborated explanation ?

Comment: It is not known for a negative number in the right-shift whether you want divide by 16 or roll in `0` bits at the top.

Comment: @AsifAhmed Undefined and implementation-defined behaviors are explained e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984). Roughly speaking, you are supposed to check documentation for your compiler. But anyway, try to avoid shifting signed negatives.

Answer (score 0):

Right shifting fills the empty bits with the sign bit. This is, it fills them with 0 if the number is positive, and with 1 if negative.

-1 = ffff = 11111111

If you shift it to the right, the resulting number will be the same.

If you don't understand why -1 = ffff, read about two's complement, wich is the representation of signed integers used by most languages.

Comment: "_Right shifting fills the empty bits with the sign bit._" It is a typical case in practice, but not guaranteed.

Comment: I got it now.  i knew that while shifting, bits are replaced by zeros only. Didnt know that it is replaced by the sign bit value during right shift.  Thank you . . @AlexD